# Jmeter Performance Test Configuration setup

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I would like to ask your help how can I simulate this scenario below. I tried to use CSV Data Set Config +  Loop Controller unfortunately some user_id are being called multiples times with in a minute.

-User_id pool = 31,000

-Number of unique users each minute: = 4000

-number of requests per user: 3 rpm

-requests per minute: 12000

Your response is highly appreciated. Thank you so much in advance.

**This is for 3 minutes execution**

[image]

[image]

Total User_id being used
[image]

**Jmeter Test Config**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

-My Expectation atleast 12k user_id is being used but on my case only = 9641

-Some user_id is being called multiple times

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't need the Loop Controller, you already have infinite number of loops on [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) level
2. You won't be able to get rid of duplicates because you expect 36000 results and have only 31000 entries in the CSV file. Set "Recycle on EOF" to `False` and "Stop Thread on EOF" to `True` if you don't want duplicates
3. I think you're getting less results because you're not achieving 200 requests per second, try either increasing the number of threads or switching to [Concurrency Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/) and connect it to the Throughput Shaping Timer via [Feedback function](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/#Schedule-Feedback-Function). See [How to Dynamically Determine the Thread Count](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeters-shaping-timer-plugin#how-to-dynamically-determine-the-thread-count) chapter for more details.

Comment: The reason I used loop controller because I want 1st set of user_id they will fire 3 requests , after next minute different set of user_id will generate again 3 requests.